# Excel VBA : Generate fxls files based on unique values in one column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file containing this sample data.

```
A          B           C        D
Entity     Container   login    mail
A          1           tutu     tutu@tutu.com
A          1           toto     tutu@toto.com
A          2           tata     tutu@tata.com
B          3           tete     tutu@tete.com
B          4           titi     tutu@titi.com
```

Column A contains 2 Entities (A and B)

I would like generate 2 Excel files based on the unique values in column A of the original above file (so the goal is to generate Entity_A.xls and Entity_B.xls)

Entity_A.xls would contains one sheet ("Users_Entity_A) containing :

```
A          B        C
Container  login    mail
1          tutu     tutu@tutu.com
1          toto     tutu@toto.com
2          tata     tutu@tata.com
```

Entity_B.xls would contains one sheet ("Users_Entity_B) containing :

```
A           B       C
Container   login   mail
3           tete    tutu@tete.com
4           titi    tutu@titi.com
```

How can I do that in VBA? The range (nb of rows) in the original file can change very often. The numbers of entities too.

Thanks in advance for all your help

Comment: How would you determine how many rows should go to file 1 and how many should go to file 2 ?

Comment: @Rockstar grouping by "Entity"

Comment: Okay, so are you sure you have fixed files to be generated based on groupings ? I mean it should be a constant, right?

Comment: Yep, the generated files will have always the same structure (same number of columns)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`autofilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) for selecting the rows under the same entity and then, copy each of them to a file.

So, for filtering the rows under `A` entities, it would be something like:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").AutoFilter _ 
 field:=1, _ 
 Criteria1:="A", _ 
 VisibleDropDown:=False
```